# Problems encountered in derivation with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have some problem when derivate with tensorflow. My code is:

```
def pde(x,y):
    x = dde.config.real.set_float64()
    u,k = y[:,0:1],y[:,1:2]
    du_x = tf.gradients(u,x)[0]
    du_x,du_y= du_x[:,0:1],du_x[:,1:2]
    du_xx = tf.gradients(du_x,x)[0][:,0:1]
    du_yy = tf.gradients(du_y,x)[0][:,1:2]
    return k*du_xx + k*du_yy
```

and the error is:

```
 f = self.pde(inputs, outputs_pde)
    File "d:/VS_CODE/AI_code/experiment/seepage_rectangle_bc.py", line 22, in pde  *
        du_x = tf.gradients(u,x)[0]

    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'op'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you print some debug? What are `u` and `x` for example.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of your function, you are overwriting `x`

```
x = dde.config.real.set_float64()
```

Change it to

```
def pde(x,y):
    dde.config.real.set_float64()
    u,k = y[:,0:1],y[:,1:2]
```